# How do I become a Substrate Developer?

Tags: polkadot, kusama, learning

I would like to become a Substrate Blockchain Developer.

What is the recommended path?

I have 4 months of Rust programming experience and 3 years of Python programming experience.

I am just starting to learn blockchain.
I am using the following steps to learn.

1. https://wiki.polkadot.network/
2. https://learnpolkadot.com/kusama/
3. https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/
4. https://web3.foundation

Comment: Dont forget https://web3.foundation/ also.

Comment: Do you have programming background or no programming background? And what is your goal with learning blockchain? You want to be a blockchain dev? Or you want to understand high-level concepts of how a blockchain works? A little info on your background and your aim would be great.

Comment: @Bruno, Added the Goal in the question.

Comment: @juancho, may you help to decide the ranking of https://web3.foundation in the learning steps?

Comment: for me, the realistic way to learn is by reading the source code of Substrate, Frontier, Polkadot...

Comment: @StefanMuto I like that approach as I would love to do it as well.

Answer (score 29):

This is a hard question to answer but I will try to give my 2 **..**'s on what was helpful for me when I started on the Substrate path as a Polkadot Support Engineer at Parity. Maybe some others can share their perspective as well.

If you have a bit of a programming background and your goal is that you want to learn blockchain to become familiar with Substrate I would recommend the following:

Learn blockchain fundamentals with Bill Laboon:

- [Blockchain Fundamentals](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxVihxZC42nF_MCN9PTvZMIifRjx9cZ2J)

Become familiar with [Substrate Docs](https://substrate.io):

- https://docs.substrate.io/v3/getting-started/overview

Do **all** the Substrate tutorials:

- https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3

Subscribe & watch videos

- [Parity Tech YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/c/ParityTech)

Learn about the [different pallets](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sc_service/index.html?search=pallet) available to you. Read them.

- Use the full Substrate [node runtime](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs) as a reference as to how to configure some of these pallets
- Pick a pallet and try to implement it yourself using the [Substrate Node Template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template)

Build stuff

- Don't be afraid to get your "hands dirty"
- Pick something that you don't know and try to learn it
- Become comfortable configuring and running nodes
- Build a pallet from scratch

Adopt a growth-mindset

- Learn a little everyday; this adds up

Keep up-to-date on what is happening in the [Polkadot community](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/community) especially the Element chats and Github.

Go deeper into Substrate:

- [Substrate How-To Guides](https://docs.substrate.io/how-to-guides/v3)

Read the docs!

- [Substrate Rust Docs](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sc_service/index.html)
- Specifically, you can start with the Substrate crate:

  - https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/substrate
- This is the Substrate Developer's bible

Read the code!

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate
- This is the Substrate Developer's home
- You should be regularly poking around in the Substrate codebase to understand how things work; don't be satisfied with concepts, you should understand how it works in the code as well.

Stay up-to-date on Stack Exchange:

- [Substrate Stack Exchange](https://substrate.stackexchange.com)
- Replicate the issues, solve them

Learn Rust as you learn Substrate:

- [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book)
- Several other resources available

Find a mentor

- Blockchain & the Polkadot ecosystem can be complex; however, the community is thriving, there are Polkadot events online and all over the world - great place to meet others who are a little further on the Substrate path

From here, you could specialize e.g. Substrate Runtime Engineer, Substrate Parachain Engineer, etc. depending on the path you want to take there are a number of additional resources available to you.

**And last but not least:**

- Participate in a Substrate-related hackathon!

**AND** participate in the **Polkadot Blockchain Academy**:

- https://polkadot.network/development/academy

Comment: Thanks for all links!

Answer (score 4):

I think the great majority of people start with substrate-kittties tutorial (https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/kitties/pt1/). I suggest you take a look at this workshop https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NrG3co6UWEg (Substrate: Blockchain Framework in Rust - Workshop at @ETHDenver). I think this workshop is very well explained and beginner friendly. If you are looking for a little bit more guidance and mentoring while you are learning substrate there is a paid course in this link: https://www.industryconnect.org/substrate-runtime-developer-academy/

Comment: I guess, Industry Connect no longer offers Substrate Runtime Developer Academy course. At least the "Apply Now" button doesn't work.

Comment: https://github.com/Polkadot-Blockchain-Academy/pba-qualifier-exam

Answer (score 3):

The answers already in here are super good. I want to add that for a lot of people "learning by doing" is a great way of getting into a new framework.

A lot of repositories related to Substrate (Substrate itself, but also parachain projects) have issues in their GitHub repositories tagged as "Good First Issue" or "Mentor available". These can serve as a good starting point for getting your hands on something and have somebody review your code.

For example in Substrate:

> https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/labels/Z1-mentor
>
> An easy task where a mentor is available.