# Any guidance for the developers that are new to Polkadot/Substrate stack?

Tags: learning

- What's the practical learning path for async / in-own-pace learning?
- Or what's the recommended "live" learning path (bootcamps, etc.)?
- Any concrete resources to use for self learning? There seem to be a lot of resources and it would take time to explore each of them. Maybe someone knows the resources that helped them to get onboarded easily?

Any type of guidance is highly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if this is in-line with your question but this may be helpful: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1074/how-do-i-become-a-substrate-developer

Comment: Thanks, Bruno and Shawn! This already gives me a very detailed answer.