# Substrate learning resources

Tags: substrateinterface

Can any one please point me to some very good step by step resource/course to learn substrate? I can't find any resources that would guide me step by step starting from substrate architecture and guide me through the whole processes of building my own frame.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the [Substrate Tutorials](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/).

Also this [post](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/1082/2762) in StackExchange from Bruno is the best summary out there to start learning Substrate.

And I would like to add a few links to it that help me and some that I found interesting too.

From Github:

- A [list of awesome](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/awesome-substrate/blob/master/README.md) things curated by the Substrate community.
- The [developer hub](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub) in Github.

Some interesting videos:

- [Substrate: A Rustic Vision for Polkadot by Gavin Wood](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0IoUZdDi5Is)
- [Substrate: Blockchain Framework in Rust](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NrG3co6UWEg)
- [Deep dive into FRAME V2 pallet macros](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5pLHzKMCEtg)
- [Substrate Seminar](https://www.crowdcast.io/e/substrate-seminar/41)

As an extra:

- If you want to go even more deeper, apply for the [Polkadot Blockchain Academy](https://polkadot.network/academy/).
- Join [here](https://substrate.io/ecosystem/resources/seminar/) to attend biweekly seminars with different topics about Substrate.
- Join the [Polkadot Forum](https://forum.polkadot.network/) to see the latest news/discussions in the space.