# How to find mentorship to become a substrate developer and land the first job?

Tags: polkadot, parachain, advice

My aim is to become a core blockchain developer (not just the smart contract developer). So I can create custom blockchain for companies to meet their business needs.

I am good with rust and previously worked on it and contributed into [rust-clippy](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy) project.

After reading through [this post](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1074/how-do-i-become-a-substrate-developer) I found great learning resources, and now my questions are :

1. How to find mentorship and land the first job?
2. What are the possible steps that can be taken to increase the likelihood of a successful career of a substrate developer?

Please Note : Currently I'm unemployed and therefore I have plenty of time to prepare myself.

Comment: You can ask all substrate related questions here and we would be happy to help!

Comment: Yes, although option based questions should live outside this platform, join us on https://forum.polkadot.network

Answer (score 1):

First, [The Polkadot Blockchain Academy](https://polkadot.network/academy/) is a unique opportunity for developers such as yourself where students will learn everything about Polkadot and Substrate directly from the core developers.

Second, I recommend you to participate in Hackatons, where you can build things and meet other people from the ecosystem.

There are a plenty being organised, just as an example a few weeks ago the [Polkadot LATAM Hackathon](https://polkadothackathonlatam.com/en/home-en/) ends with lot of interesting projects and next week you have [Polkadot Metaverse Championship](https://metaversechampionship.gg/).

And finally you have [Substrate Seminar](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-seminar),  is an online meet-up for learning all things Substrate. You can learn and ask questions to the people building amazing things.
Subscribe on [Twitch](https://www.twitch.tv/polkadotdev).

There is no one-way answer to your questions, but if you dive into all the information provided and you put in the time, I'm sure you'll come a long way!